# Kazam shortcut keys not working in Gnome 3

Tags: gnome, 13.10, shortcut-keys, kazam

I am using Gnome 3.10 on the top of Ubuntu 13.10 and the stock kazam screencaster coming with Ubuntu (1.4.3-0ubuntu1).

Kazam works properly, however the start/pause/finish [shortcuts](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/kazam-screencaster-132-gets-new-ui.html) are not working at all. They're supposed to be Super+Ctrl+R, P and F respectively.

It used to work properly with Unity. Do you have any idea what's blocking them in Gnome3?

---

**UPDATE Feb 12, 2014:**

I realized that several times the shortcuts worked but not always and not consistently.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the default screen-caster *(it might be the same thing... I don't know...)* that comes with Gnome - just use the keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

If you go the 'Keyboard' settings and then 'shortcut', you can change this shortcut:

[image: Gnome Keyboard Settings]

You can also remove any other keyboard short-cuts that may override the ones you specified.

More [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/CheatSheet#Screencast_recording)

Comment: Thank you wilf, I saw the builtin screencast tool as well, however one major thing I'm missing is that I can't pause/resume it. I frequently create screencasts with that "technique" so that I don't have to cut/edit them after. That's the very reason kazam has been very handy for me.

Comment: The problem is probably due to it last being supported for 13.04 Raring Ringtail... Did you do this: `sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kazam-team/stable-series/ubuntu raring main"
` for the repository, instead of the `ppa` from the article? It seems to work in Unity using that...

Comment: Well kazam is included by default in Ubuntu 13.10, moreover it is the latest version at the time of writing this 1.4.3.

Comment: I didn't have it... I had to install it. I dunno...